# Python ctypes time(0) and C time(0)

Tags: python, c, binary, ctypes, ctf

So i was doing the 2019 picoCTF binary challenge seed-sPRiNG where i got this [write up](https://github.com/Dvd848/CTFs/blob/master/2019_picoCTF/seed-sPRiNG.md)
with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
  
int main () 
{ 
    int i;
      
    srand(time(0)); 
    
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", rand() & 0xf); 
    }
      
    return 0; 
}
```

So i thought of implementing the same in python. At first i used the random module but realized the C rand and pythons are miles apart in their implementation so i decided to use ctypes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from ctypes import CDLL

libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")

libc.srand(libc.time(0))


for i in range(30):
    print(libc.rand() % 0xf)
```

But i still get different output when i run them both, Can i get an explanation why this is so

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  `&` vs. `%`.

Answer (score 2):

In your Python version, you modded by `0xf` instead of taking the bitwise `&` operation. In other words, you modded the results by 15 instead of 16. If I switch the Python version to use `&` instead of `%`, I get the same results on my machine.